# What do I return from the query function of datasource.js for grafana log panel datasource plugin?

Tags: javascript, dataframe, grafana

I am trying to  reproduce  the steps given in [grafana log data source plugin](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/developers/plugins/build-a-logs-data-source-plugin/)
so that I can replace the current-query function with a  hardcoded log-panel compatible query function
in oci-datasource-plugin
[Github link| oci-datasource-file](https://github.com/oracle/oci-grafana-plugin/blob/master/src/datasource.js)

From the documentation of log-panel build guide

```
      const frame = new MutableDataFrame({
        refId: query.refId,
        fields: [
          { name: 'time', type: FieldType.time },
          { name: 'content', type: FieldType.string, labels: { filename: 'file.txt' } }
        ],
      });
    
      frame.add({ time: 1589189388597, content: 'user registered' })
      frame.add({ time: 1589189406480, content: 'user logged in' })
```

1. The documentation suggests to return a Frame.
2. The steps given shows a Mutable data frame.
3. But the panel expects a response.

If a frame is returned instead of a response data, the following error appears
[image: Error for returning a frame or frame.json()]

Based on the  working code found in  [Github link| oci-datasource-file](https://github.com/oracle/oci-grafana-plugin/blob/master/src/datasource.js)

for a different panel type , I modified my code  to return a  response with data inside it.

My response look this and replacing the data with

```
   result.data = frame.toJSON()
   return result
```

Also, if you can paste a working sample data that I can look at , it will be really helpful.
To be more precise, I am looking for the sample json data for  log panel

Comment: I encountered a similar problem recently, but it looks like we actually had somewhat different problems. Curious if you ran into other issues or have ideas that might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66575053/grafana-logs-plugin-doesnt-show-logs-panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into one of the test files in Grafana | [LogDetails.test.tsx](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/blob/master/packages/grafana-ui/src/components/Logs/LogDetails.test.tsx)

Looks, like it must be  returned  must be  returned as

```
result.data = [frame]
return result
```